# How to loop for transaction in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to do the transaction in mongoodb using Fawn npm modules. 
I have written the code below and it's working fine. But if item is an array has multiple elements, how can I perform the same action. In that case, I need to save order only one time but update the stock multiple time.

I tried to loop over but the order is saved two times and there is an error which I'm getting is `MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: db.orders index` It's because I'm saving same order multiple time.

```
try {
    new Fawn.Task()
      .save('orders', order)
      .update(
        'items',
        { _id: item[0]._id },
        { $inc: { stock: -+req.body.quantity[0] } }
      )
      .run();
  } catch (ex) {
    res.status(500).send('Something failed');
  }
```

where item is the list of all item's ID that I have to update.

I want to update the order single time and other item multiple times based on the size of the item array.

When I'm doing this, It works absolutely fine. 
But I want it to be dynamic, as I won't be knowing the size of the array.

[image: hard coded code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally chain it like the following:

```
try {
  let task = new Fawn.Task()

  //
  task = task.save('orders', order)

  //
  for (let i in item) {
    task = task.update(
      'items', {
        _id: item[i]._id
      }, {
        $inc: {
          stock: - +req.body.quantity[i]
        }
      }
    )
  }

  task.run();

} catch (ex) {
  res.status(500).send('Something failed');
}
```

You might want to add validation.

Answer (score 0):

there is subtract operator that can aslo be used, instead of updating field with a negative value. 
Like below

{ $subtract: { stock: req.body.quantity[i] } }

for reference do [check](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/)